Transfer SPL tokens with web3 from seed account based on the System Program Id
Can I transfer SPL tokens from the seed account (PDA) based on the System Program Id created this way:
let derivedAccount = await PublicKey.createWithSeed(usualAccountPublicKey, seed, SystemProgram.programId)

to a usual account with JavaScript and web3 libraries?

A account-with-seed is unfortunately not the same thing as a program-derived address, and cannot be used as the owner of an SPL token account.
If you want to transfer from an account owned by a PDA, then it must be done from within a program. It's only possible to "sign" for PDAs from within a program, so there's no way to do it with JavaScript / web3.js.
You can learn more about program-derived addresses at https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/pdas.html#facts

Actually, this is possible to have an account-with-seed as an owner of SPL token account.
You can reproduce it by these steps:


await PublicKey.createWithSeed()


transfer from some wallet (I used Phantom) tokens to created address


call method
await connection.getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner(accountWithSeed, {mint: mintPubkey}), so you will receive SPL token account, owned to account-with-seed



You can certainly create the token account and transfer tokens into it, but it's impossible transfer any tokens out of those accounts
